# Various writing proposals on Area51

Tags: discussion, technical

On Area51 Discuss, bigown [proposes merging](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155/what-about-merging-with-writers) two proposals in the definition phase with us, namely:

1. [Technical Writing](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/8847/technical-writing), and
2. [Blogging and Copywriting](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/10929/blogging-and-copywriting).

Do we want to encompass these forms of professional writing?  If so, how do we reach out to these potential contributors?

Comment: "Do we want"?  The question should be: "don't we already?"  I though we were.

Answer (score 10):

I say yes -- this site desperately needs an infusion of content and audience to survive.

And isn't writing.. writing? I suppose there is a sort of divide between the fiction and non-fiction folks, but certainly the goal of writing clearly and communicating well is shared by all these audiences.

edit: this is now complete, see:

https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/ask
https://writers.stackexchange.com/faq

and

https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155/what-about-merging-with-writers

Comment: I agree, but there seems to be a feeling that this site is unfriendly towards anything that isn't fiction, specifically novels.

Comment: @neilfein - I hear this said, but no one actually seems hostile to this content.  What does seem to be the case is that some non-fiction writers have looked at the site and not found it interesting.

Comment: It's going to be tough for this site to survive even with these proposals added into the mix.  It should probably be done ASAP.

Comment: @mark I have closed these proposals as dupe of writers and I'll update the faq